# Array reduce with object as initial value

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain what's going on with `reduce` function in the below example, I have an object with keys and empty arrays as the initial value for `reduce` method, I would like to have step by step explanation inside reduce method

```js
initExercises = {
  shoulders: [],
  chest: [],
  arms: [],
  back: [],
  legs: []
}

exercises = [

  {
    id: "overhead-press",
    title: "Overhead Press",
    description: "Delts exercise...",
    muscles: "shoulders"
  },

  {
    id: "dips",
    title: "Dips",
    description: "Triceps exercise...",
    muscles: "arms"
  },

  {
    id: "barbell-curls",
    title: "Barbell Curls",
    description: "Biceps exercise...",
    muscles: "arms"
  },

  {
    id: "bench-press",
    title: "Bench Press",
    description: "Chest exercise...",
    muscles: "chest"
  },

  {
    id: "pull-ups",
    title: "Pull Ups",
    description: "Back and biceps exercise...",
    muscles: "back"
  },

  {
    id: "deadlifts",
    title: "Deadlifts",
    description: "Back and leg exercise...",
    muscles: "back"
  },

  {
    id: "squats",
    title: "Squats",
    description: "Legs exercise...",
    muscles: "legs"
  }

];


console.log(
  exercises.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const {
      muscles
    } = curr;
    acc[muscles] = [...acc[muscles], curr] //what's happening here?
    return acc;
  }, initExercises)
)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: @FZs It's likely a typo when OP extracted the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: it was a typo...

Comment: acc[muscles] = [...acc[muscles], curr] i wanted to know what's happening here and how it works with inititalExercises

Comment: @Seblor I've suspected that, but didn't correct it because a **lot** of questions' problems originate from typos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reduce` function explained:

```js
exercises.reduce((acc, curr)=>{ /*...*/ }, initExercises)
```

...will...

- put `initExercises` into `acc`, and `exercises[0]` into `curr`
- then put the prevoius iteration's return value into `acc` and the current element to `curr`
- finally, it returns the last iteration's return value.

This snippet:

```js
const {
    muscles
} = curr;
```

...extracts the `muscles` property from the object `curr` (which is an element of the `exercises` array) to the constant `muscles`.

Then, this:

```js
acc[muscles] = [...acc[muscles], curr]
```

...creates a new array, [spreads (`...` syntax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the previous one for the same muscle (located in the `acc`umulator object's property pointed by the (just destructured)  `muscles` variable) into it, and appends the `curr`ent object at the end; and finally replaces the old array in `acc[muscles]` (the property pointed by `muscles`) with that new array.

Lastly, it `return`s the `acc`umulator, to keep it for the next iteration.

So the function returns an object, in which the array's elements are grouped by their `muscles` property.

---

Iterations in detail:

```
# | acc           | curr                         | muscles       | [...acc[muscles], curr]                           | return value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 | initExercises | {id: "overhead-press", ... } | "shoulders"   | [{id: "overhead-press", ... }]                    | {shoulders: [{id: "overhead-press", ... }], chest: [], arms: [], back: [], legs: []}
1 | return of #0  | {id: "dips", ... }           | "arms"        | [{id: "dips", ... }]                              | {shoulders: [{id: "overhead-press", ... }], chest: [], arms: [{id: "dips", ... }], back: [], legs: []}
2 | return of #1  | {id: "barbell-curls", ... }  | "arms"        | [{id: "dips", ... }, {id: "barbell-curls", ... }] | {shoulders: [{id: "overhead-press", ... }], chest: [], arms: [{id: "dips", ... }, {id: "barbell-curls", ... }], back: [], legs: []}
...
```

Comment: shouldn't it be somethin like "acc[muscles] : [...acc[muscles], curr]" since acc is an object with key as muscle and value as array, i'm confused

Comment: When you **create** or **destructure** an object (`{...}`), you use `:`. If you assign a value to something (either variable or object property), you use `=`

Comment: acc[muscles] is an array, got it, initially the acc[muscles] = curr, i.e curr is the first object in the exercises array, in next iteration curr will be second object from the exercises array, then the value of acc[muscles] = [curr2] and then. But acc is initialExercise is an object with key as muscles and value as array, how does it group?

Comment: what exactly the value of acc[muscles] in every iteration and how does it group with the initialExercise, i'm really having hard time getting my head around it

Answer (score 0):

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), `acc[muscles] = [...acc[muscles], curr]` equal to `acc[muscles] = acc[muscles].concat(curr)`, e.g. adding `curr`ent exercise to group with key `muscles`

Comment: acc[muscles] = [...acc[muscles], curr] i wanted to know what's happening here and how it works with inititalExercises

Comment: "curr'' iterates through every object in the exercises array, and what is acc[muscles] in every iteration?

Comment: On every iteration `acc` is the result of a previous iteration, for first iteration is `initial`.
Reference on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Examples) have really nice examples.